# sas metadata user synchronization with more repository

Tags: sas, sas-metadata

I have an environment with 2 repositories:

1. Foundation: User \ Group (same as LDAP users)
2. [Repository 2]: access group and ACT

Normally the 2 repositories are linked.

an example:

- I create in Foundation [USER1], [GROUP1] and the association [USER1] in [GROUP1]
- I create in [Repository 2] [GROUP2], [ACT1] and associate the
  [GROUP2] in [ACT1]
- In the properties of [metadata Folder1] I assign the [GROUP2] and the
  [ACT1]

In the process of extracting the star-schema (developed through the [[SAS standard](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=bisecag&docsetTarget=p0z36im6qsfk3ln1advg12dn5lls.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)) I cannot find the association of point 2 illustrated above, whether you download the data from the Foundation or from the [second repository].

How can I find this data? and once found can this information be updated through the SAS procedure?

thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

Niko